# Longest Common Prefix Per Aggregate Using Apache Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using apache spark to find the longest common prefix per session

---

Given the following example:

```
session | prefix
_____________________
1       | keys
1       | key chain
1       | keysmith
2       | tim
2       | timmy
2       | tim hortons
```

I would like to format this into the following output:

```
session | prefix
_____________________
1       | key
2       | tim
```

I saw an [example](https://explainextended.com/2009/06/04/longest-common-prefix-sql-server/) which checks a column in one row against all others but I have trouble wrapping my head around how to do this for aggregate rows.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
select session,min(length(prefix)) from table_name
group by session
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for the above example how would I be able to "trim" session 1 to "key"?